# Android Studio 3.2.1: “Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found”

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 3.2.1:

> Error initializing ADB: Android Debug Bridge not found

And I installed all the required components.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did u find a fix to this?

Comment: Not yet. Maybe reinstall os can fix this.

Answer (score -1):

I met this situation and the issue was with the "platform-tools". Some how it was broken, 
I have done the following to fix it,

1. Download the latest platform-tools from the official site (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools).
2. Rename the current "~\Android\Sdk\platform-tools" to "~\Android\Sdk\platform-tools-OLD".
3. Unzip the downloaded zip file(eg:-platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip) and copied it to "~\Android\Sdk\"
4. Now you have the updated platform-tools in the SDK directory, restart Android Studio by File->"Invalidate Caches and Restart".

   Hope this helps.